# Elasticsearch query for "nested" object (without type: nested)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble to create a ElasticSearch query for my current dataset / mapping. My current mapping:

```
"products": {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "active": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "properties": {
          "created_at": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
           }
         },
         "id": {
           "type": "long"
         },
         "language_code": {
           "type": "text",
             "fields": {
             "keyword": {
               "type": "keyword",
               "ignore_above": 256
             }
           }
         },
         "product_column_id": {
           "type": "long"
         },
         "product_id": {
           "type": "long"
         },
         "value": {
           "type": "text",
           "fields": {
             "keyword": {
               "type": "keyword",
               "ignore_above": 256
             }
           },
         }
       "id": {
         "type": "long"
       },
       "published": {
         "type": "long"    
       }
},
```

I want to query my dataset (products) so I can select all products with certain attributes. Every attribute will need to match multiple criteria. Example:

Get all products having at least the attribute with product_column_id = 2 AND value = '3'.

I tried all the things I can think / read of like:

```
'bool' => [
  'must' => [
    [
      'match' => [
        'attributes.product_column_id' => 2
      ]
    ],
    [
      'match' => [
        'attributes.value' => '3'
      ]
    ],
  ]
]
```

I also tried to use filters:

```
'bool' => [
  'filter' => [
    [
      'match' => [
        'attributes.product_column_id' => 2
      ]
    ],
    [
      'match' => [
        'attributes.value' => '3'
      ]
    ],
  ]
]
```

But still I get all products containing attributes with value 4 without the correct product_column_id (it is searching for the term "4" in the whole value field. So not exactly matching.

I use PHP / Laravel / Elasticquent to format my queries but that shouldn't matter.

Can anyone tell me how to format a query to match products containing attributes who are matching not only the value but also the product_column_id (and for the future: language_code)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't use keyword nested in nested data then it's all flatten means no relations are  kept. i.e there will be no relation between `attributes.product_column_id` and `attributes.value`

Comment: Hmmm .. so adding the type: nested should solve the problem? I'm now reading on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html and there it is saying exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, this would. Try queried with the nested query

Comment: It works! I had to manually create the index because the Elasticquent library cannot be used for manual index mapping (not in combination with Elastic Search 7) but it works now!